# Boundary of 127 for integers in Java

Tags: java, integer, equality, boxing

Out of curiosity: why do we have **FALSE** when the integer is greater than 127, for `Integer`s?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(127 == 127); // case 1: true
        System.out.println(128 == 128); // case 2: true
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(127) == Integer.valueOf(127)); // case 3: true
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(128) == Integer.valueOf(128)); // case 4: FALSE
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare `Integer` with `==` use `equals` instead

Comment: [It's in the documentation of `Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)).